# What is a tensorflow float ref?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Trying to run the following basic example to run a conditional calculation I got the following error message:

> 'x' was passed float incompatible with expected float_ref

what is a tensorflow float_ref and how does the code have to be modified?

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.ops.control_flow_ops import cond

a = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.),name="a")
b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.),name="b")
x = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.),name="x")

def add():
    x.assign( a + b)
    return x

def last():
    return x

calculate= cond(x==0.,add,last)

with tf.Session() as s:
    val = s.run([calculate], {a: 1., b: 2., x: 0.})
    print(val) # 3
    val=s.run([calculate],{a:4.,b:5.,x:val})
    print(val) # 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`float_ref` here refers to a reference to a float, i.e. your Tensorflow float variable `x`.

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49479197/2110869) you are facing this error because **you can't simultaneously assign and pass a variable as a feed_dict** in the same session run like you are doing in this statement:

```
val = s.run([calculate], {a: 1., b: 2., x: 0.})
```

It becomes more obvious when you resolve that statement to end up with:

```
val = s.run([x.assign( a + b)], {a: 1., b: 2., x: 0.})
```

Answer (score 3):

FYI.
I got a similar error and mine was:

> node GradientDescent/update_input/ApplyGradientDescent was passed float from _arg_input_0_1:0 incompatible with expected float_ref.

This happened because somewhere in my node-tree I had a `tf.Variable` instead of a `t.fplaceholder`. After replacing the variable with the placeholder, it worked.

Answer (score 2):

this doesn't explain what a float_ref is, but it fixes the issues:

1) variables need to be created in the session
2) assignment op was not what we expected

this fixed code works:

```
def add():
    print("add")
    x = a + b
    return x

def last():
    print("last")
    return x

with tf.Session() as s:
    a = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.),name="a")
    b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.),name="b")
    x = tf.constant(-1.)
    calculate= cond(x.eval()==-1.,add,last)
    val = s.run([calculate], {a: 1., b: 2.})
    print(val) # 3
    print(s.run([calculate],{a:3.,b:4.})) # 7
    print(val) # 3
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
a = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.),name="a")
b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.),name="b")
x = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.),name="x")

def add():
    x.assign( a + b)
    return x
```

to:

```
    a = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,name="a")
    b = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,name="b")
    x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,name="x")
    def add():
        x= a + b
        return x
```